# Integrate WEBRTC with OpenMCU

Tags: webrtc

I have implemented multi party video+audio chat using Star Network with WebRTC. I am not using any third party cliend SDK's to achieve it.In this case one peer acts like a relaying party(router). So the steps the super node does 1) Get its own video stream and pass to the peer by calling addstream 2) get remote video stream in"onaddstream" method and add it to the existing peer connection and send it across. Everything works fine but since there is an existing issue in chrome code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2192 the audio cant be relayed. Now I want to promote the implementation to use MCU (especially OpenMCU) on windows machine. How can I tweak my existing application (which uses core WebRTC apis) to use the MCU.

Comment: How is anybody supposed to know what you need to tweak when you are very vague about your current solution?

Comment: Well as I pointed out my current solution uses the star topology where in one peer acts like a router (supernode) and relays video coming from different peers. So the steps the super node does   1) Get its own video stream and pass to the peer  by calling addstream 2) get remote video stream in"onaddstream" method and add it to the existing peer connection and send it across. Everything works fine but since there is an existing issue in chrome https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2192 the audio cant be relayed. Hence how to tweak existing flow to use open source MCU

Comment: Replace your central node with an MCU and use the chosen MCU api for the connections

Comment: Thanks I understand that but I am planning to deploy on windows box and the mcu's mainly support Linux. I found this OpenMCU but does not have sufficient documentation of how use its API.